# TypeError: post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path' in FastApi?

Tags: python, fastapi

Where is mistake in FastApi?

Error is:

> @video_router.post('/info')
> TypeError: post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'

api.py

```
from fastapi import APIRouter
video_router = APIRouter
@video_router.post('/info')
async def info_set(info: UploadVideo):
    return info
```

main.py:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from api import video_router
app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(video_router)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is here.

```
video_router = APIRouter
```

`video_router` must be an [instance of](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/?h=apirouter#import-apirouter) `APIRouter` class ***not the reference to the class itself***. So change it to

```
video_router = APIRouter()
```